# GAE Occasionally stops serving for 1-5 minutes

Tags: google-app-engine

Starting about 1 week ago, my app will occasionally and randomly completely stop serving for 1-5 minutes. Requests during this time hang for the full timeout and then return a 500.

The System Status dashboard reads OK, I have no cron jobs or anything special that might cause this disruption (that I know of).

Has anyone experienced this, and is there a solution?

Answer (score 0):

If you have 'threadsafe: false' in your app.yaml configuration, App Engine will not send concurrent requests to your app. If you have a request that's blocking for a really long time, all other requests coming in will line up (and possibly time out) before being serviced. If this is the cause of your problem, either make your app thread-safe or have a look in your logs to find requests that take a long time and fix them.

Alternatively, if your app gets very little traffic, your instances might be getting shut down after they've been idle for a while. If your app takes a long time to start up, that would explain the behavior you're seeing. In app.yaml, you can set 'min_idle_instances' to some value greater than zero to avoid this startup penalty.